# Android : Enroll finger print in Emulator using Telnet

Tags: android, android-emulator, fingerprint

I have tried to enroll a finger print in emulator using command telnet 127.0.0.1 5554 finger touch 1. But it not working. When I tried telnet 127.0.0.1 5554 it connects to the emulator. Thenhow can I add a finger print.Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The new Android emulators bundled with Android Studio have a more (...) button at the bottom of the floating toolbar.  In the fingerprint settings is a button to generate a sensor touch event.  Go into Android settings, and when registering a new fingerprint, hit the button in the emulator's extended controls window.